# Google Charts JSON loading double quotes

Tags: json, jquery, google-visualization

I try to parse data from a JSON constructed in a php file based on this guide:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example?hl=en

I have created my JSON in a good way but when I use this code it seems that it does not read the JSON well:

```
function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "loader.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
```

I think there is some trouble with the double quotes in the JSON's keys since in [this example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) the Javascript object doesn't have quotes. So somewhere I should miss something?

My scripts code is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


      function drawChart() {

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
                dataType:"json",
                url: "loader.php",
                async: false
                }).responseText;

        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);



        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {title: 'Results', width: 400, height: 240});

    }
    </script>
```

And the source code of what my `loader.php` returns is:

```
{"cols": 
   [{"label":"Sources","type":"string"},
    {"label":"Count","type":"number"}],
"rows":
   [{"c":[{"v":"web"},{"v":"4757"}]},
    {"c":[{"v":" iPhone"},{"v":"4324"}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Android"},{"v":"3294"}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"BlackBerry\u00ae"},{"v":"2336"}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Instagram"},{"v":"951"}]}
   ]}
```

Note: the chart loads well without errors but does not load the JSON. It says: Other 100%. So neither the labels nor the rows are correctle loaded.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't load the JSON? The numbers aren't actually numbers, so there is no way for Google to display a pie chart (since there are no values to display). What is displayed after the code runs? What is the alert of `alert(data.getValue(1,1))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values must not be quoted. Remove the quotes, eg

```
var jsonData={"cols": 
   [{"label":"Sources","type":"string"},
    {"label":"Count","type":"number"}],
"rows":
   [{"c":[{"v":"web"},{"v":4757}]},
    {"c":[{"v":" iPhone"},{"v":4324}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Android"},{"v":3294}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"BlackBerry"},{"v":2336}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Instagram"},{"v":951}]}
   ]};
```

And the chart is working.

**NB** : Be aware of BlackBerry\u00ae, you have some decoding/encoding issue in your loader.php (but that is not what caused the problem)